# How to Best Raise (One-Time) the Beginning of a New Chapter on a New Page

Tags: vertical-alignment, chapters, page, vertical-spacing, vertical

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large

\textbf{Introduction}

%\vspace*{-50pt}
\chapter*{\textcolor{red}{Chapter 1}}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

which produces the new chapter

[image]

Every once in a while, I need to vertically lift the starting point for a new chapter on a new page. If I am not generating an endnotes list, something like `\chapter*{\vspace*{-50pt}{Chapter 1}}` generally works fine; however, for large documents where I produce such a page, such a command causes a blemish in both the endnotes display, as well as in the TOC where such is indicated (at least for the algorithm I use).

Moreover, in the MWE, if I comment-out  `%\vspace*{-50pt}`---it has no effect on the output.

QUESTION: How may I selectively raise the starting point of a new chapter on a new page without resorting to something like `\chapter*{\vspace*{-50pt}{Chapter 1}}`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large

\textbf{Introduction}

\AddToHookNext{cmd/@makeschapterhead/before}{\vspace*{-50pt}}
\chapter*{\textcolor{red}{Chapter 1}}
\lipsum[3]

\chapter*{\textcolor{red}{Chapter 1}}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```